# Bitangent lines to polygons and polygon sets

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons, tangent-line

I have a set of simple, non-overlapping polygons and I want to find all bitangent lines.

A bitangent line is defined as a line by two vertices such that the two incident edges are on the same side of the line, in pairs. A single polygon can also have bitangents.

[image]

All bitangent lines to a set of polygons can easily be found by brute force: consider all pairs of vertices ($O(n^2$) of them) and check if the other endpoints of the incident edges are on the same side of the line they define.

[image]

I wonder if a faster solution can be found. Has any algorithm been published on this problem ?

Additional question: is my terminology correct ?

---

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the bitangents are allowed to cross the polygons (except at the tangency vertices). I have updated the figure to show this possibility.

I am not sure if the simplicity of the polygon helps (bitangency actually remains defined for independent pairs of edges), but it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

[See the OP's comment below; I misread the question, but this still may be useful, so I'll leave it up.]

A key search term here is the *visibility complex*. Pocchiola & Vegter have written several papers on the topic. This is probably the best place to start.

> Pocchiola, Michel, and Gert Vegter. "Topologically sweeping visibility complexes via pseudotriangulations." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 16.4 (1996): 419-453.
>   ([PDF download](https://pure.rug.nl/ws/files/3253463/1996DiscrCompGeomPocchiola.pdf).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: VisComplex]

---

They specialize to a set of convex objects, and substantially improve the 
naive algorithms to run in $O(n \log n)$ plus output size.

Comment: Many thanks. I am not fully sure that this is a visibility problem, as the bitangents are allowed to cross the polygons elsewhere (they have even more freedom than the free bitangents). I should have mentioned that explicitly, sorry. Anyway, the visibility complex must be close to my needs. I wonder if this allowance makes the problem easier or harder.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Oh, sorry for my hasty post. Then I do not know of a method faster than trying all pairs of vertices, which would require quadratic time. In fact, it seems $\Omega(n^2)$ is a lowerbound: sawtooth polygons.

Comment: You are quite right: without restrictions, there can be a quadratic number of solutions and brute force is optimal. Unless there exists an output-sensitve algorithm with a better behavior (?) But now I realize that $n^2$ solutions is too much for my purpose (finding interesting features in an image). So I am thinking to add a criterion such as "for every vertex, find the closest bitangent buddy,if any".